# GraphQL: Could not resolve to a PullRequest with the number of 1153. (repository.pullRequest)

Tags: github

Why am I getting this error?

```bash
$ gh pr checkout 1153
GraphQL: Could not resolve to a PullRequest with the number of 1153. (repository.pullRequest)
```

The PR does exist in the Repository so it make no sense to me.

#### Additional info:

I am working with a repository from:

https://github.com/minio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you might be in the wrong repository.
Sometimes developers work in different repositories and they expect a branch to be present in the wrong spot; please double-check on the repo. For instance if I try the same command in the wrong repository where the PR is not located, then I get the same error:

```bash
# Change directory to Console Repo where the PR is NOT located
cd ~/console
$ gh pr checkout 1153
GraphQL: Could not resolve to a PullRequest with the number of 1153. (repository.pullRequest)
```

#### Solution:

```bash
# Change directory to proper Repository:
cd ~/operator
gh pr checkout 1153
```

> As a result:

```
$ gh pr checkout 1153
Switched to branch 'add_ingress_for_tenant'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the default remote repository was wrong and was actually set to the repo that my repo was a fork of when I cloned my repo onto my local system with the GitHub CLI.

**Check the current default repo:**

```bash
$ gh repo set-default --view
```

**If it's wrong, you can interactively set it:**

```bash
$ gh repo set-default
```

**Or set it explicitly:**

```bash
$ gh repo set-default owner/repo
```